# Get definite schema information for Microsoft Graph requests

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I have an Office JavaScript add-in. We handle our own license workflow. Part of the workflow is to use *`office-js-helpers`* to handle Microsoft logging. The user uses the Microsoft endpoint to log in and we receive an *access token* which we send to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` to retrieve user data. Some users are individual Microsoft users, others are part of an organization.

Recently, I've noticed that the `givenName` field is not provided, and it's causing errors in ingestion. I find it hard to design a schema to handle user data coming from MS Graph, since I have not seen any schema information for the possible responses to `me` request.

Can someone point me to where MS lists the definite schema for it's Graph requests? Is there a request URI for that kind of info?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying object schema could be determined by specifying `odata=fullmetadata` [JSON control level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/payload-format-for-table-service-operations) as demonstrated below:

```
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Method: Get
Headers
   Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false
```

which returns *the type name of the containing object* (`odata.type` annotation), in case of `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint it is `#microsoft.graph.user`

And then via [Microsoft Graph API metadata endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/traverse_the_graph#microsoft-graph-api-metadata):

```
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata
Method: Get
```

where `microsoft.graph.user` entity schema could be found under under `Schema` element for `Namespace="microsoft.graph"`:

```
<EntityType Name="user" BaseType="microsoft.graph.directoryObject" OpenType="true">
    <Property Name="accountEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
    <Property Name="ageGroup" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="assignedLicenses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedLicense)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="assignedPlans" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedPlan)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="businessPhones" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="city" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="companyName" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="consentProvidedForMinor" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="country" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="department" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="deviceKeys" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.deviceKey)" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="employeeId" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="givenName" Type="Edm.String" />
    ...
  </EntityType>
```

Comment: So, a weird note. If a user creates an account when trying to sign in to Office.com, the user is not prompted for `givenName` and can use that account to log in through the MS OpenAuth authentication. The result is a `/me/` object that has a null value for `givenName`. That unexpected behavior is what prompted this question